# How to get randomly generated array to reset in simple memory game with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm sorry if this has been asked before,
I've searched through Stackoverflow but couldn't find anything that answered my problem.

I'm building a simple memory game, an online version of Simon, when you click the "Start" button it runs the code below to create a random array (of length 4) out of the four colour buttons.
But when you click "Start" again for the next round it doesn't clear the array, and instead creates a second one, and then checks your input against both telling you you're both right and wrong, or right and right (depending on the random array created out of the buttons).

I've tried `buttonsToClick = []` in the else section, but it doesn't reset.
I don't know what I'm missing, I've only been learning JavaScript/jQuery for about a month but I wanted to test my knowledge.

The code snipped:

```
var score = 0;

$("#score").html(`${score}`);

$("#button5").on("click", function() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("js-button");
    var buttonsToClick = chooseRandomButtons(buttons);
    currentButtons = buttonsToClick;
    flashButtons(buttonsToClick, 0);

  var currentOrder = 0;
  $(".js-button").on("click", function() {
    var selectedButton = $(this)[0];
    var button = currentButtons[0];
    if (selectedButton === button) {
        currentButtons.splice(button,1);
        /*alert("Correct");*/
        score += 1;
        $("#score").html(`${score}`);
    } else {
        currentButtons = buttonsToClick;
        alert("Wrong. Click 'Start' to try again");
        score = 0;
        $("#score").html(`${score}`);
    }
  });
})

function chooseRandomButtons(buttons) {
    var buttonsToClick = [];
    var maxRandomNumber = buttons.length - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        buttonsToClick.push(buttons[randomIntFromInterval(0, maxRandomNumber)]);
    }

    return buttonsToClick;
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function flashButtons(buttonsToClick, index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(buttonsToClick[index]).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
        if (index === buttonsToClick.length - 1) {
            return;
        }
        flashButtons(buttonsToClick, index = index + 1);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: You should be getting a JS error relating to the line `var maxRandomNumber = buttons.length - 1;` - `buttons` is set in a different scope to the function it's referenced in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO.

In general you're doing anything correct with your arrays.
The issue is your event handler.

Every time you click the `#button5`, which I guess is the start button, you register on all your `.js-button` a new listener. Since you're not unbinding the old event listeners they're still active.
Since the old event listeners have a reference to your old array, you're basically checking the button against the old game and the new game.

Your solution would be to unregister the old one before registering the new one.
This could be done for example by the `.off` method.
Your code should then look like this:

```js
var currentOrder = 0;
  $(".js-button").off("click").on("click", function() {
    var selectedButton = $(this)[0];
    var button = currentButtons[0];
    if (selectedButton === button) {
        currentButtons.splice(button,1);
        /*alert("Correct");*/
        score += 1;
        $("#score").html(`${score}`);
    } else {
        currentButtons = buttonsToClick;
        alert("Wrong. Click 'Start' to try again");
        score = 0;
        $("#score").html(`${score}`);
    }
  });
```

Notice the `.off()` there.
The documentation about the method could be found here: https://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Thank you for the welcome, and thank you that absolutely fixed my issue. I'll read the documentation after work, they're not going to be fans of me reading anything while sat on the till.